# $L^{2}$ convergence of the solution of the incompressible Navier-Stokes' to the solution of the incompressible Euler as viscosity tends to $0$.

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I am attempting to solve the following problem:

Assuming that $H^{m}(\mathbb{T}^{n})$($\mathbb{T}^{n}$ is the torus) solutions to the incompressible Euler and incompressible Navier-Stokes' exists for $n=2,3$, $m>2+\frac{n}{2}$ and $t \in [0,T]$ in the following cases:

Euler:
$$
u_{t}+u\cdot \nabla u=-\nabla p ;
$$

$$
\nabla \cdot u=0 ;
$$

$$
u(x,0)=u_{0}(x) \in H^{m}(\mathbb{T}^{n}); 
$$

$$
sup_{[0,T]} ||u||_{H^{m}} \leq A.
$$

Navier-Stokes (with viscosity $\epsilon \in (0,1)$):
$$
u^{\epsilon}_{t}+u^{\epsilon} \cdot \nabla u^{\epsilon} = - \nabla p + \epsilon \nabla ^{2}u^{\epsilon};$$

$$
\nabla \cdot u^{\epsilon}=0; 
$$

$$
u^{\epsilon} (x,0)=u_{0}(x) \in H^{m}(\mathbb{T}^{n}).
$$

$$
sup_{[0,T]} ||u^{\epsilon}||_{H^{m}} \leq A.
$$

Notice that the equations that we are considering have the same initial data $u_{0}$ and external force $p$. Also here $A>0$ is a constant.

Show that
$$
sup_{[0,T]}||u-u^{\epsilon}||_{L^{2}} \leq C \epsilon
$$
Where $C$ depends only on $A$ and $T$.

My attempt involved deriving a differential inequality. I begun by taking the dot product of Euler equation with it's solution $u$ and integrating over the Torus to obtain:
$$
\frac{1}{2} \frac{d}{dt} ||u||_{2}^{2}=\int_{\mathbb{T}^{n}} u \cdot \nabla u \cdot u dx + \int_{\mathbb{T}^{n}}  \nabla p \cdot u dx =0. 
$$

I also took the dot product of the Navier-Stokes equation with it's solution $u^{\epsilon}$ to obtain:
$$
\frac{1}{2} \frac{d}{dt} ||u^{\epsilon}||_{2}^{2}=\int_{\mathbb{T}^{n}} u^{\epsilon} \cdot \nabla u^{\epsilon} \cdot u^{\epsilon} dx + \int_{\mathbb{T}^{n}}  \nabla p \cdot u^{\epsilon} dx + \epsilon ||\nabla u^{\epsilon}||_{2}^{2} =0.
$$
Subtracting the second equation from the first and using the well known fact that:
$$
\int_{\mathbb{T}^{n}} v \cdot \nabla v \cdot v dx=0, 
$$
we obtain that
$$
\frac{1}{2} \frac{d}{dt} ||u-u^{\epsilon}||_{L^{2}}^{2} + \epsilon ||\nabla u^{\epsilon}||_{L^{2}}^{2} + \int_{\mathbb{T}^{n}} \nabla p \cdot (u-u^{\epsilon})dx = 0.
$$
This implies that
$$
\frac{1}{2} \frac{d}{dt} ||u-u^{\epsilon}||_{L^{2}}^{2} \leq \int_{\mathbb{T}^{n}} \nabla p \cdot (u^{\epsilon}-u)dx \leq ||\nabla p||_{L^{2}} ||u-u^{\epsilon}||_{L^{2}}. 
$$
i.e. This is a differential inequality of the form:
$$
\frac{1}{2} \frac{d}{dt} y^{2} \leq C y
$$
which simplifies to:
$$
\frac{d}{dt} y \leq C.
$$
My issue is here is that I don't obtain an estimate in-terms of $A$ or $\epsilon$ after integrating.

Any help on how I could solve this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The pressure function $p$ is not an external force, but is part of the problem for both the Euler and NS equations. There is no reason to think it is the same in both systems. So I think the problem is not correctly posed.